# Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be diferentiable $n$ times in $x_0$ s.t. $f'(x_0)=\dots=f^{(n-1)}(x_0)=0$ and $f^{(n)}(x_0)\neq 0$. Show that.

Tags: real-analysis

> (a) If $n$ is even and $f^{(n)}(x_0)>0$, then $x_0$ is a local maximum
>   point of $f$.
>
> (b) If $n$ is odd, then $x_0$ is not an extreme value of $f$.

I'm trying this:

If $f^{(n-1)}(x_0)=0$ and $f^{(n)}(x_0)>0$, then $x_0$ is a maximum point of $f^{(n-2)}$. Can I say that if $f^{(n-3)}(x_0)=0$ and $x_0$ is a maximum of $f^{(n-2)}$, then $x_0$ is a maximum of $f^{(n-4)}$?

Comment: Is (b) correctly stated? or is this problem actually "Show one of these", not show both? I ask because (b) is false, and you will note directly contradicts (a).

Comment: I guess you meant "(b) if $n$ is odd, then $x_0$ is neither a maximum nor a minimum of $f$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we'll need a previous result.

Let $f$ be a real-valued function. Let $P_{n,x_0}$ denote the $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $x_0$, meaning

$$P_{n,x_0}(x)=a_0+a_1(x-x_0)+\ldots+a_n(x-a)^n$$ where $\displaystyle a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}$

> **Lemma:** If $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $n$ times diferentiable in $x_0$, then
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-P_{n,x_0}(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0$$

Rewriting the expressions:

$$\frac{f(x) - P_{n,x_0}}{(x-x_0)^n}=\frac{f(x)-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i}{(x-a)^n}-\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}$$

Consider $Q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i$ and $g(x) =(x-x_0)^n$, so we must show that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-Q(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}$$

Notice that $Q^{(i)}(x_0)=f^{(i)}(x_0)$ for $i\leq n-1$ and that $g^{(i)}(x) =n!\frac{(x-x_0)^{n-i}}{(n-i)!} $ so we can use $n-1$ times L'Hôpital rule:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-Q(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f^(n-1)(x)-Q^(n-1)(x)}{n!(x-x_0)}=\frac1{n!}lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f^(n-1)(x)-Q^(n-1)(x)}{(x-x_0)}=\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}$$

(In the last equality we simply use the definition of derivative) QED

Now let's suppose $f$ $n$ times diferentiable such that $f^{(i)}(x_0)=0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$. Without loss of generality, let's suppose $f(x_0)=0$ as well (otherwise we can work with $g = f -f(x_0)$.) So we have from the previous lemma:

$$0=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-P_{n,x_0}(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\left[\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^n}-\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}\right]$$

Hence by continuity, if $x$ is close enough to $x_0$, then both $\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^n}$ and $\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}$ have the same sign.

Then if $n$ is even, $(x-x_0)^n>0$ for every $x\neq x_0$ so for $x$ close enough,   $f(x)$ and $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ have the same sign. If $f^{(n)} (x_0)>0 $, then $f(x)>0=f(x_0)$ and $x_0$ is a local minimum. With an analogous argument we can see that if $f^{(n)}(x_0)<0$ then $f(x_0)$ is a local maximum.

Now let's suppose $n$ is odd. Then $(x-x_0)^n >0$ when $x>x_0$ and $(x-x_0)^n<0$ when $x<x_0$. But $\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}$ has always the same sign. Hence $f(x)$ has diferent signs for $x<x_0$ and  $x >x_0$, so $f(x_0)$ is neither a maximum nor a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you ask about is not true in general. I suggest you consider the function $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x^n}$. And it might be best to work inductively.